# Is there a Spring Transaction Manager that works with MySQL Cluster/J (that is NDB not JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql

I'm looking for a Spring transaction manager what will work with MySQL's Cluster/J.  I can't be the first person to want to use declarative transactions with Cluster/J but I can't find an existing manager.  Have you seen one?

Comment: Did you find something in the end? I know it's an old question, but I am very curious. Thanks.